# CORS header not working for Django backend- Angular frontend

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework, cors, http-options-method

I implemented CORS on my Django backend by installing `django-cors-headers` and following the steps mentioned in- `https://github.com/OttoYiu/django-cors-headers`. Essentially, I performed the following steps-

1. `pip install django-cors-headers`
2. `INSTALLED_APPS = (
   ...
   'corsheaders',
   ...
   )`
3. `MIDDLEWARE = [
   'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
   ...
   ]`
4. `CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
   'localhost:8000',
    #LB
   '10.254.138.226:443'
   )`

I still can not make it work when I use my angular front-end. For example, my POST request becomes OPTIONS.

`zone.js:2935 OPTIONS https://10.254.138.226/api/users 0 ()`
`error is ProgressEvent {isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, loaded: 0, total: 0, type: "error", …}`

I don't have this problem when I use postman. Could someone help?

To provide more context- I have the front end and the back end (DRF) running on two different machines. In fact, I have 2 instances of the back end running in two different machines and I have a load balancer mapping the requests from `<LB IP>:443` to one of the `<Backend IP>:8000` base-url.

Answer (score 0):

I will possibly never find out the exact issue as to why it was happening. I just deleted and recreated the LB and everything started working automagically.